# Hide "Show Header and Navigation" Arrows & Other Upper Right Icons

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, microsoft-lists

In a Modern List View, I am looking for a way to hide some or all, via JSON, of the **upper right corner icons** for "All Items" view selector, "Open the Filters Pane", "Open the Details Pane",  and the "Show Header and Navigation" Arrows.

Can this be done by amending the Formatted List View JSON that I use to hide the Command Bar elements?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": false,
        "text": "Add a New Nomination"
      },
      {
        "key": "editInGridView",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "share",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "automate",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "export",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "integrate",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to hide "Switch view options" drop down (All items & other view options), Filters Pane, Details Pane ( i ) and [Expand/Collapse content (focus mode](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/21/introducing-focus-mode-for-modern-sharepoint-pages/) options from top side of the SharePoint online list view using JSON command bar formatting.

Currently you can only hide the below options which are supported in `key` property:

```
'new'
'newFolder'
'newWordDocument'
'newExcelWorkbook'
'newPowerPointPresentation'
'newOneNoteNotebook'
'newFormsForExcel'
'newVisioDrawing'
'upload'
'uploadFile'
'uploadFolder'
'open'
'share'
'copyLink'
'download'
'rename'
'copyTo'
'moveTo'
'delete'
'edit'
'comment'
'editNewMenu'
'powerBI'
'powerBIVisualizeList'
'automate'
'automateCreateRule'
'automateManageRules'
'powerAutomate'
'powerAutomateCreateFlow'
'powerAutomateSeeFlows'
'powerAutomateConfigureFlows'
'aiBuilderCreate'
'aiBuilderGoto'
'aiBuilder'
'alertMe'
'newLink'
'integrate'
'manageAlert'
'powerApps'
'powerAppsCreateApp'
'powerAppsSeeAllApps'
'powerAppsCustomizeForms'
'viewDocumentUnderstandingModels'
'versionHistory'
'openInImmersiveReader'
'classifyAndExtract'
'checkOut'
'checkIn'
'undoCheckOut'
'properties'
'pinItem'
'exportExcel'
'exportCSV'
'export'
'editInGridView'
'exitGridView'
'sync'
'uploadTemplate'
'addTemplate'
'openInOfficeOnline'
'openInOfficeClient'
'addShortcut'
'pinToQuickAccess'
'unpinFromQuickAccess'
```

**Documentation**: [Command bar customization syntax reference - key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting#key)

Comment: OK Thank you Ganesh.  
Is there any other way to keep the navigation (formerly Quick Launch) bar closed to all viewers?

Comment: You want To hide navigation From all users?

Comment: Yes. On many lists, I need to keep users focused on the list. They should not wander to other site content.

Comment: You can do it at site level and not at specific list/library level. Can you please [Ask a new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with details and provide link here? I will try to explain the steps in detailed answer.