# SPO: Hide Quick Launch, Side Navigation, and Site Contents Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, navigation, hide-elements

Springing from a previous question below, I need to hide various page elements or functions from users.

If I am unable to hide the Hide/Show Navigation arrows at the upper right corner, how can I hide the ability to see Quick Launch, including Site Contents?

([Hide "Show Header and Navigation" Arrows & Other Upper Right Icons](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308201/hide-show-header-and-navigation-arrows-other-upper-right-icons/308203?noredirect=1#comment325457_308203))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide quick launch / site navigation by following these steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint site
2. Click on Settings (Gear) icon > Select **Change the look**
3. Select **Navigation** option
4. Turn **Off** site navigation visibility
5. Click Save

**Reference**: [New Navigation features for SharePoint team sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/)

[image]